# How to map caps + h,j,k,l to arrows with russian lang?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I have  xmodmap config:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym h = h H Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym k = k K Up
keysym j = j J Down
keysym u = u U Prior
keysym i = i I Home
keysym o = o O End
keysym p = p P Next
```

All works nice, but when I change layout, these keys dont work ;( 
Help pls, I wasted 3 days already searching solution.

Comment: I have messed with stuff like this and unfortunately the new xkb system is not as flexible/forgiving.  In fact I would argue it has less options.  Try maybe setting CapsLock to AltGr equivalent and then use the AltGr layout to modify those keys to the ones above.